# Generate tag file only for C++ files(.h, .cpp, .cxx, .c)

Tags: c++, linux, vi, ctags

I am working in a code base of C/C++ files on Linux.

I want to jump to definition of a function when pressing <kbd>Ctrl [</kbd> inside vim .

For this I am generating a tag file by running

```
ctags --language-force="c++" -R *
```

but it is scanning .xml, .js, and other non C++ files. As a effect, the ctags command is taking more time to finish and the tags file size is also increasing.

Is there any way of generating tags file only for C++ files(.h, .cpp, .cxx, .c)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try --languages option instead of --language-force option:

```
ctags --languages="c++,c" -R *
```